# getting "Not Found (JIRA::HTTPError)" while using jira-ruby gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jira, jira-rest-api

I am trying to execute jira-ruby(https://github.com/sumoheavy/jira-ruby) command line example program.

```
    username = "username"
    password = "password"

    options = {
      :username => username,
      :password => password,
      :site => 'https://company.atlassian.net/',
      :context_path => '/myjira',
      :auth_type => :basic
    }

    client = JIRA::Client.new(options)

    puts client
    # Show all projects
    projects = client.Project.all

    projects.each do |project|
      puts "Project -> key: #{project.key}, name: #{project.name}"
    end
```

I have used real username, password and site url. I am getting following error:

```
    /home/tuka/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/jira-ruby-0.1.16/lib/jira/request_client.rb:16:in `request': Not Found (JIRA::HTTPError)
        from /home/tuka/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/jira-ruby-0.1.16/lib/jira/client.rb:159:in `request'
        from /home/tuka/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/jira-ruby-0.1.16/lib/jira/client.rb:138:in `get'
        from /home/tuka/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/jira-ruby-0.1.16/lib/jira/base.rb:96:in `all'
        from /home/tuka/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/jira-ruby-0.1.16/lib/jira/base_factory.rb:33:in `block (2 levels) in delegate_to_target_class'
        from atoj.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

I done debugging..

```
    /home/tuka/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/jira-ruby-0.1.16/lib/jira/http_client.rb:38:          http_class = Net::HTTP
    (rdb:1) n
    /home/tuka/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/jira-ruby-0.1.16/lib/jira/http_client.rb:40:      http_conn = http_class.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    (rdb:1) n
    /home/tuka/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/jira-ruby-0.1.16/lib/jira/http_client.rb:41:      http_conn.use_ssl = @options[:use_ssl]
    (rdb:1) http_conn
    #<Net::HTTP company.atlassian.net:443 open=false>
    (rdb:1) n
    /home/tuka/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/jira-ruby-0.1.16/lib/jira/http_client.rb:42:      http_conn.verify_mode = @options[:ssl_verify_mode]
    (rdb:1) http_conn
    #<Net::HTTP company.atlassian.net:443 open=false>
    (rdb:1) n
    /home/tuka/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/jira-ruby-0.1.16/lib/jira/http_client.rb:43:      http_conn
    (rdb:1) http_conn
    #<Net::HTTP company.atlassian.net:443 open=false>
    (rdb:1) n
    /home/tuka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1373:      unless started?
    (rdb:1) n
    /home/tuka/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1374:        start {
    (rdb:1) n
    /home/tuka/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/jira-ruby-0.1.16/lib/jira/http_client.rb:26:      store_cookies(response) if options[:use_cookies]
    (rdb:1) 
    n
    /home/tuka/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/jira-ruby-0.1.16/lib/jira/http_client.rb:27:      response
```

But everything looks okay to me.

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the *context_path* to empty, e.g. ''. This worked for me.

In case that is also not working try the Jira UI and look for the first path element of the URI (shown before "/browse" and "/issues"). This is most likely also the context_path.

Answer (score 1):

You have to parse the Jira URL to get all its components separatly using [Ruby URI module](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html).

```
# Parsing URL
uri = URI.parse('https://company.atlassian.net/myjira') # Your Jira URL
site = uri.scheme+'://'+uri.host # Protocol + Domain

options = {
  :username => username,
  :password => password,
  :site     => site,
  :context_path => uri.path, # SubURI path
  :use_ssl => false,
  :auth_type => :basic,
  :read_timeout => 120
}

JIRA::Client.new(options)
```

This solution works for me ;)